# Intuition behind random matrices

Tags: probability, pca, intuition, wishart-distribution

I am looking for an intuition for random matrices. Say, Gaussian or Binary squares matrices to begin with. I am considering three possible viewpoints:

- As a $n$ random points in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- As a random linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
- As a network of pair-wise distances between $n$ randomly positioned points.

I wonder which gives more insight? To Wishart theory? To statistical properties of PCA? etc...

Comment: Are you asking about the **motivation** to study random matrices?  Wishart was originally interested in sample covariance matrices but these days it's hot mainly due to the connection to statistical physics.  Loosely, instead of studying non-random but complicated self adjoint operators, you look at simpler but random self adjoint matrices, the canonical version featuring normal random variables.

Comment: @P.Windridge I think he's asking about ways to interpret distributions over random matrices.

Comment: @ssdecontrol : Then I think the question is too vague :)

Comment: @P.Windridge I agree

Comment: @ssdecontrol: yes. I am looking for ways to interpret distributions over matrix spaces.

Comment: @JohnRos that, I think, comes down to "how do I interpret a matrix?" which, the way you've phrased it, is a good question but is probably better asked on [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I disagree. I think that for most if not all purposes, a matrix is best interpreted as a linear operator. But trying to visualize _random_ linear operators I find to be a harder task than random clouds of points.

Comment: When you mention PCA, do you imagine that your random matrix is a covariance matrix? Or Gram matrix? Or data matrix? What connection with PCA do you have in mind?

Comment: Getting down to basic ideas, it might be good to start with the concept of a "random point in $\mathbb{R}^n$": what do you understand that to be?  The next step would be to consider whether you are limiting your matrices to be of a certain type, such as positive definite, symmetric, orthogonal, binary, etc.  (I have no idea what a "Gaussian" matrix would be, though.)  Some of these types of matrices--such as the orthogonal or binary ones--form *compact manifolds* for which there are built-in, natural, geometrically meaningful distributions (given by their Haar measures).

Comment: @whuber: this is a good point. The intuition I am looking for is actually of the geometry of the support. For this reason I only need to figure out what class of matrices lay in the support, and then recur to basic matrix theory.

Comment: That helps focus our attention, John, but it's a very broad request.  Do you have specific sets of matrices in mind?  And just what kind of intuition are you looking for?